# Foreign Key issue with migrations

Tags: laravel

Im using the package https://github.com/musonza/groups to added group system on my laravel app, but when I want to migrate I get the error:

```
Migration table created successfully.
Migrating: 2019_05_26_125854_create_groups_tables

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `groupsystem`.`#sql-2678_26` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `groups` add constraint `groups_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)
```

This is my 2 migrations table code:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

And also this is the migration table I get from installing the package:
That I mentioned in the link in the top of this post 
This is the first time I try to use this package
And im trying tocreate a group system on my laravel application
Any other suggetions will be welcomed

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateGroupsTables extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('groups', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('short_description')->nullable();
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->string('url')->nullable();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->boolean('private')->unsigned()->default(false);
            $table->integer('conversation_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->text('extra_info')->nullable();
            $table->text('settings')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });

        Schema::create('group_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('group_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('group_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('groups')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });

        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->string('type');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->text('extra_info')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });

        Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('body');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('type')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users');

            $table->foreign('post_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('posts');
        });

        Schema::create('group_post', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('group_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('group_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('groups')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('post_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('posts')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });

        Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('user_id')->index();
            $table->integer('likeable_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('likeable_type');
            $table->primary(['user_id', 'likeable_id', 'likeable_type']);
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('reports', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('user_id')->index();
            $table->integer('reportable_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('reportable_type');
            $table->primary(['user_id', 'reportable_id', 'reportable_type']);
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('group_request', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('group_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('group_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('groups')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('groups');
        Schema::drop('group_user');
        Schema::drop('posts');
        Schema::drop('comments');
        Schema::drop('group_post');
        Schema::drop('likes');
        Schema::drop('reports');
        Schema::drop('group_request');
    }
}
```

Comment: Paste your migration code here

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using? If you are using `Laravel 5.8` then please follow - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Comment: @NatvarsinhParmar-bapu ok I will edit 
Im using Laravel 5.8

Comment: It's done I just edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have used laravel 5.8 then

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

If you have used laravel  < 5.8 then

```
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

Answer (score 1):

I did found the solution it's because of the new Laravel 5.8.3 it comes with unsignedBigInteger(id) instead of increments(id)

Comment: bigincrements instead of increments but yea you should use unsignedBigInteger